# Using a custom template for actionbar menu item

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I am trying to display a menu with text and icon always visible. I have defined my item layout as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_cart"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:text="(0)"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

And the menu is defined as following

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.taptoscan.taptoscan.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_sign"
        android:title="(0)"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_sign" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

I'm having an issue with enabling the ripple effect on the background. It works but the ripple effect is not rounded, lik on a regular menu icon. It's square shaped and looks kinda ugly. What would be the best way to achieve the native ripple effect look on a custom menu item?

EDIT: This is what it looks like

[image]

Comment: the only way to do this is to make a custom view which extends `TextView` then apply some logic to make It round

Comment: @MohamedRa Managed to come up with a solution, posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE: Better solution found, check the edit**

I figured it out. First I created a background drawable with rounded corners, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <padding
            android:bottom="5dp"
            android:left="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:top="5dp" />

        <corners android:radius="5dp" />

    </shape>
</ripple>
```

After that, I set the TextView's background as the drawable from above. Ripple effect works as intended and it's all rounded like on default menu items.

[image]

**EDIT**

After further messing around with the custom menu item, I have found out that just by using a TextView without a root element will cause TextView's baseline to be changed after clicking on another menu item and then clicking back on the custom one. The solution is using the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_actionbar_icon">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/icon_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_cart"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="(0)"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```